# Whether a MoM estimator is mean-square consistent

Tags: statistics

Original question: "$Let$ $X_1$$,$$X_2$$,...,$$X_n$ $be$ $a$ $random$ $sample$ $from$ $the$ $exponential$ $distribution$ $having$ $pdf$

$f($$x$$|$$\theta$) $=$ $\theta$$e^{-\theta x}$$,$ $x>0$

$where$ $\theta$ $>$ $0$ $is$ $an$ $unknown$ $parameter$ $and$ $n$ $\geq$ $3$

Find the method-of-moments estimator,$\hat\theta$, of $\theta$

Let T = $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ $X_i$. Given that

E[$T^{-1}$] = $\frac{\theta}{n-1}$ (n=2,3,...) and E[$T^{-2}$] = $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ (n=3,4,...), determine whether $\hat\theta$ is unbiased, asymptotically unbiased and mean-square consistent.

Workings:
$\frac{1}{\hat\theta}$ = $\bar{X}$

$\hat\theta$ = $\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$ {MoM estimator)

E[$\hat\theta$] $=$ E[$\frac{1}{\bar{X}}$] = E[$\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i}$] $=$ E[$\frac{n}{T}$] $=$ $\frac{n\theta}{n-1}$ $\neq$ $\theta$ so $\hat\theta$ is biased

As $n$ $\rightarrow$ $\infty$, $\frac{n\theta}{n-1}$ $\rightarrow$ $\theta$, so $\hat\theta$ is asymptotically unbiased.

Here comes the one where somewhere I've gone wrong on, but I'm unsure of where.

MSE[$\hat\theta$] $=$ Var[$\hat\theta$] $+$ $(B(\hat\theta))^2$ $=$ Var($\frac{n}{T}$) + $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$ $=$ E($\frac{n^2}{T^2}$) $-$ $(E(\frac{n}{T}))^2$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$

$=$ $n^2$E($T^{-2}$) $-$ $($nE($T^{-1}$)$)^2$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$

$=$ $n^2$$\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $-$ $n^2$$\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$

$=$ $\frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $-$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$$(1-n^2)$

$=$ $\frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2(n-1)(n+1)}{(n-1)^2}$

$=$ $\frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2(n+1)}{(n-1)}$

Now, I can tell that from here that as n goes to infinity, this does not go to 0. However, from the answers I know that $\hat\theta$ IS mean-square consistent. So clearly I've gone wrong somewhere, but I can't see where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rewrite the MSE formula without first substituting the estimator into it:

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{MSE}[\hat \theta] 
&= \operatorname{Var}[\hat \theta] + \operatorname{Bias}[\hat \theta]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta^2] - \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta]^2 + \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta - \theta]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta^2] - \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta]^2 + (\operatorname{E}[\hat \theta] - \theta)^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta^2] - \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta]^2 + \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta]^2 - 2\theta \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta] + \theta^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta^2] - 2\theta \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta] + \theta^2. \tag{1}
\end{align}$$

In fact, we could have obtained this directly from the definition of MSE:  $$\operatorname{MSE} \overset{\text{def}}{=} \operatorname{E}[(\hat \theta - \theta)^2] = \operatorname{E}[\hat \theta^2] - 2 \operatorname{E}[\theta \hat \theta] + \operatorname{E}[\theta^2],$$ because the mean square error is the expected squared deviation of an estimator from the parameter it estimates.

In any case, now we can substitute our results, recalling that $\hat \theta = n/T$.

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{MSE}[\hat \theta]
&= \operatorname{E}[(n/T)^2] - 2 \theta \operatorname{E}[n/T] + \theta^2 \\
&= n^2 \operatorname{E}[1/T^2] - 2n\theta \operatorname{E}[1/T] + \theta^2 \\
&= \frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}  - \frac{2n\theta^2}{n-1} + \theta^2 \\
&= \left(\frac{n^2}{(n-1)(n-2)} - \frac{2n}{n-1} + 1\right) \theta^2 \\
&= \frac{n+2}{(n-1)(n-2)} \theta^2. \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

Thus as $n \to \infty$, the MSE indeed tends to $0$.  I prefer using the formula $(1)$ because when we know the first two moments of the estimator, it doesn't require us to have calculated the bias.

So, where did you go wrong?  You have a sign error in this step:

$$\frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)} - n^2 \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2} + \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2} = \frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)} - \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2} (1 - n^2).$$  The correct expression should read:

$$\frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)} - n^2 \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2} + \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2} = \frac{n^2 \theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)} \color{red}{+} \frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2} (1 - n^2).$$

Once you correct this error, your result will agree with $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that the

$n^2$$\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $-$ $n^2$$\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$

$=$ $\frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $-$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$$(1-n^2)$ is an incorrect factorisation, and actually it should be

$=$ $\frac{n^2\theta^2}{(n-1)(n-2)}$ $+$ $\frac{\theta^2}{(n-1)^2}$$(1-n^2)$

from this the result follows